# Creating a reusable qmenu python

Tags: python, pyside

So i have a simple example here. A widget with 2 widgets in it's ui.
What I want to do is have a different qmenu popup depending on which widget the user is hovering over.

What I want to do...
- move the actual menu items into a separate file of their own core_rcmenu, so i can keep organized.

```
self.cmenu_edit = QtGui.QMenu()
self.mi_add_new_node = self.cmenu_edit.addAction('Add New')
self.mi_add_new_node.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
self.cmenu_edit.addSeparator()
self.mi_rename_node = self.cmenu_edit.addAction('Rename')
```

Then when the user right-clicks, the function which gets called, i will pass a variable determining which qmenu to show. The reason for this is to one, put the qmenu in its own file and keep the UI's clean, and secondly the qmenu is shared across multiple widgets and some widgets appear in other files.

[image]

```
 # Imports
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    import sys
    from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtSvg


    # Main
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class ExampleA(QtGui.QWidget):

        def __init__(self,):
            super(ExampleA, self).__init__()

            self.initUI()


        def initUI(self):
            # formatting
            self.resize(550, 400)
            self.setWindowTitle("Factions")

            # context menu - passes
            self.cmenu_edit = QtGui.QMenu()
            self.mi_add_new_node = self.cmenu_edit.addAction('Add New')
            self.mi_add_new_node.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
            self.cmenu_edit.addSeparator()
            self.mi_rename_node = self.cmenu_edit.addAction('Rename')

            # widget
            self.treeA = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
            self.treeB = QtGui.QTreeWidget()

            # signals
            self.treeA.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
            self.treeA.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_context_menu_open)

            self.treeB.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
            self.treeB.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_context_menu_open)


            # layout
            self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
            self.mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
            self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.treeA, 0,0)
            self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.treeB, 0,1)


            # display
            self.center_window()
            self.show()


    # Functions
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        def center_window(self):
            qr = self.frameGeometry()
            qr.moveCenter(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
            self.move(qr.topLeft())

        def on_context_menu_open(self, pos):

            # pass a varaible such as "TreeA" or "TreeB" which would determine
            # items to be displayed in menu
            self.cmenu_edit.exec_( QtGui.QCursor.pos() )


    # Main
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = ExampleA()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Updated**
Here is my attempt:

```
# Imports
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtSvg


# Main
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ExampleA(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,):
        super(ExampleA, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        # formatting
        self.resize(550, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Factions")

        # widget
        self.treeA = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
        self.treeB = QtGui.QTreeWidget()

        # signals
        self.treeA.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.treeA.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_context_menu_open_a)

        self.treeB.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.treeB.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_context_menu_open_b)

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.treeA, 0,0)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.treeB, 0,1)


        # display
        self.center_window()
        self.show()


# Functions
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def center_window(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        qr.moveCenter(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def mi_add_new_node_clicked(self):
        print "adding item"

    def mi_rename_node_clicked(self):
        print "rename item"

    def prompt_right_click_menu(self, widget, _type):
        cmenu_edit = QtGui.QMenu()
        mi_add_new_node = cmenu_edit.addAction('Add New')
        mi_add_new_node.triggered[()].connect(self.mi_add_new_node_clicked)

        if _type == "B":
                cmenu_edit.addSeparator()
                mi_rename_node = cmenu_edit.addAction('Rename')
                mi_rename_node.triggered[()].connect(self.mi_rename_node_clicked)


        cmenu_edit.exec_( QtGui.QCursor.pos() )

    def on_context_menu_open_a(self, pos):
        self.prompt_right_click_menu( self.treeA , "A")

    def on_context_menu_open_b(self, pos):
        self.prompt_right_click_menu( self.treeB , "B" )



# Main
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ExampleA()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: To share different type of menus between several widget, I would store the menus in a dictionary and pass it in the `__init__` of the widgets. Then you could do something like `self.menuDict[_type].exec_()` .

Comment: What do you mean by reusing a QMenu? A QMenu just contains some QActions. Do you really want to perform the same actions when calling the context menu on different widgets? If yes, why don't you just do it?